# Template Haskell - How to lookup type operator name?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

How do I lookup type operator name? This does not work:

IssueTH.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module IssueTH where
import Language.Haskell.TH

f :: Q [Dec]
f = do
    Just n <- lookupTypeName "GHC.TypeLits.*"
    return []
```

Issue.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Issue where
import IssueTH

$f
```

`ghc Issue.hs` fails with message:

```
Pattern match failure in do expression at IssueTH.hs
```

Replacing `"GHC.TypeLits.*"` with `"GHC.TypeLits.(*)"` or `"*"` doesn't work either.

Comment: 1. You're missing `import GHC.TypeLits` in the second file, without that it wouldn't work even with a non-operator type. 2. After fixing that, this still looks like a bug to me, so I [reported it](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11046#ticket).

Comment: I [just discovered](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11046#comment:1) that it works if the type operator starts with `:`, so my guess is the function wasn't updated when their syntax was liberalized.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen, I lookup fully qualified "GHC.TypeLits.*", I don't think I need import GHC.TypeLits there, but it still doesn't work even with import as you see.

Comment: The `*` operator doesn't work with or without import, or with or without qualification. But for e.g. `Nat`, you need an import, even with a fully qualified name (and it works without qualification too). Testing a bit further, it respects `qualified` and `hiding` on the import too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I have enough now for a brief answer. Alas I only found the reason for your problem, but not how to solve it.

My testing shows that `lookupTypeName` *does* support type operators, but only if they start with `:`.

Originally this was a requirement, in analogy with infix data constructors, but this was lifted to allow things like the arithmetical type operators in `GHC.TypeLits`. (The downside is that you can no longer have type operator *variables*, as were once popular for things like `Arrow` code.)

Presumably `lookupTypeName` was not updated to take this into account, and I have [filed a bug report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11046) for this.

EDIT: A fix for this has finally been made, and should be in the upcoming GHC 8.2.1.